# Retornar nome no lugar do ID da chave estrangeira

Tags: python, banco-de-dados, python-3.x, sqlite3, chave-estrangeira

Estou desenvolvendo um sistema em Python e queria retornar dados do banco especifico, só que no lugar da id da chave estrangeira eu queria retornar o nome dessa pessoa.

A criação das tabelas:

```
self.cursor.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS pessoas(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,nome TEXT, cpf TEXT UNIQUE, tipo TEXT, nascimento DATETIME, telefone TEXT)")

self.cursor.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS doacoes(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, doador_id INTEGER, litros INTEGER, tipo TEXT, FOREIGN KEY(doador_id) REFERENCES pessoas(id))")
```

Função que retorna os dados da tabela doação:

```
def consultar_estoque(self):
        estoque = self.cursor.execute("SELECT * from doacoes ORDER BY id DESC")
        self.db.commit()
        return estoque.fetchall()
```

Como eu disse acima, ele retorna o id, porém queria o nome da pessoa relacionada àquele ID. Para isso eu teria que fazer outra consulta? Ou existe uma forma mais fácil pra realizar o relacionamento?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Olá, tem duas forma que eu conheço para resolver seu problema:

- Primeira Forma

```
def consultar_estoque(self):
    estoque = self.cursor.execute("""SELECT doacoes.nome,
                                     doacoes.litros,
                                     doacoes.tipo,
                                     pessoas.nome FROM doacoes, pessoas WHERE
                                     pessoas.id = doacoes.doadorID
                                     ORDER BY id DESC""")
    self.db.commit()
    return estoque.fetchall()
```

Aqui você retornei todos os dados da tabela `doacoes` e o nome do doador da tabela `pessoas`.

- Segunda Forma

```
def consultar_estoque(self):
    estoque = self.cursor.execute("""SELECT doacoes.litros,
                                            doacoes.tipo,
                                            doacoes.doador_id,
                                            pessoas.nome FROM doacoes, pessoas INNER JOIN pessoas ON doacoes.doador_id=pessoas.id""")
    self.db.commit()
    return estoque.fetchall()
```

Os duas instruções são bem parecidas e eu não sei explicar porque usar uma ou outra e nem a peformance de cada uma delas, infelizmente.

Comment: Muito obrigado!!